# onGesturePerformedListener with SurfaceView and animation Thread

Tags: android, view, surfaceview, gestures

I am working on a children's game for Android that uses gestures and 2d animation.  I have three classes in the game: the main activity, the SurfaceView (for the animation), and a thread to control the animation.  Pretty simplistic stuff.  I have gestures working the way I want.  And I have the scene working the way I want.  The problem is, I would like the scene to react as the user performs the gesture.  So, there is a star on the scene.  I would like the child to trace the star (preloaded as a gesture) but as he traces it, I would like to animate the star.  I have put a number of logs to see if the thread is firing, but it is not receiving messages.  So, basically, I want the the two to work in tandem - I want to the onGesturePerformedListener to grab the touch event, and I want the surfaceView to grab the same touch event.  Both need to react to it.  Like I said, I have them working independently brilliantly, but I need them to work at the same time.  What am I missing?

Main Activity:

```
mGameView = (GameView)findViewById(R.id.gamearea);
mGameView.setStatusView((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text));
mGameView.setScoreView((TextView)findViewById(R.id.score));
mGestureView = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gestures);
mGestureView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

This class also holds the onGesturePerformed method.

SurfaceView: (This is the method that sets the thread.)

```
public void setThread(GameThread newThread) {

    thread = newThread;

    setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(thread!=null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Touched the screen");
                return thread.onTouch(event);
            }
            else return false;
        }

    });

    setClickable(true);
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

Thread:

```
    //Finger touches the screen
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch Fired");
        return false;
    }
    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        dotX = e.getX();
        dotY = e.getY();
        Log.d(TAG, "Updating Dot by touch.");
        return true;
    }

    if(mMode == STATE_READY || mMode == STATE_LOSE || mMode == STATE_WIN) {
        doStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "doStart Loaded");
        return true;
    }

    if(mMode == STATE_PAUSE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "mode is paused");
        unpause();
        return true;
    }

    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "synchronized");
            this.onTouch(e);
    }

    return false;
}
```

My working theory is that everything hinges on the placement of the overlayview - this is where I have a breakdown in understanding.  The main.xml, which is what the Main activity is set to (seen above) looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gestures"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

<com.trial.game.test.GameView
  android:id="@+id/gamearea"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/score"
      android:text="@string/score_text"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="top"
      android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
      android:textSize="24sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="3px"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:text="@string/mode_ready"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
      android:textSize="20sp"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Based on the placement of the gestureoverlay or the gameview one or the other will fire, but not both at the same time.  What I am overlooking or misunderstanding here.  Anyone?